# Get values out of collections with FastMember

Tags: c#, asp.net, fastmember

I use FastMember to get values out of objects and nested objects. If a property is a `string` or `int` everything works fine. But now I want to get the values also for collections. Here is my code so far:

```
// Set accessor
var sourceAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(source);

if (sourceAccessor.Target.GetType().GetInterface(nameof(ICollection)) != null || sourceAccessor.Target.GetType().GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null)
{
    foreach (/* idk */)
    {
        // READ & RETURN VALUES HERE
    }
}
```

An object could look like this:

```
{
Id: 1,
Surname: Doe,
Prename: John,
Professions: [
    { Name: ab },
    { Name: xy }
]
}
```

Which means professions would result in a problem.

Any advise how I can solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: In your example is `source` an instance of your 'person'-like object, or an array of professions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious from the question what the data type of the `source` variable is, but you should just be able to check if the value returned by the accessor implements `IEnumerable` or not and act accordingly.

Here's a quick worked example that iterates over the Professions property of a 'Person' object and just dumps the `ToString()` representation to the console - if you wanted to dive into each Profession object using FastMember you could construct another `ObjectAccessor` to do it, I guess - it's not clear what your goal is once you're iterating.

The same tactic will work if you're building the `ObjectAccessor` directly from an array - you just check if the `accessor.Target is IEnumerable` and cast-and-iterate in a similar fashion.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Person
        {
            Professions = new List<Profession>
            {
                new Profession("Joker"),
                new Profession("Smoker"),
                new Profession("Midnight toker")
            }
        };

        var accessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(p);
        var professions = accessor[nameof(Person.Professions)];

        if (professions is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var profession in (IEnumerable)professions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(profession);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    public List<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
}

class Profession
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Profession( string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```